# How to check jQuery find return true or false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="child1">Child1</div>
    <div class="child2">Child2</div>
    <div class="child3">Child3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
    <div class="child1">Child1</div>
    <div class="child2">Child2</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
alert($(".parent1").find(".child3").text());
alert($(".parent2").find(".child3").text());
```

My question is how to check `find` function return true or false?

In above code it return blank value, where `parent1` class have `child3` class where `parent2` class do not have `child3` class.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3bx11qe/2/)**

Comment: `find` doesn't return a boolean value.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You couldn't use just `find` in `if` condition. You could use `has` or check for the `length` property.

```
var elm = $('.parent1');
if(elm.has('.child3')){
   var child3 = elm.find('.child3');
}
```

Or simply like this

```
var child3 = $('.parent1').find(".child3");
if(child3.length > 0) {
  // child3 is present
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation (https://api.jquery.com/has/) the 'has' method returns jQuery, not a boolean. Meaning that the first example in this answer will always return true. Using the example on the documentation page, you need to check if the length property of the returned object is greater than zero and not simply that something has been returned.

Comment: `has` doesn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.length` property to check that element exists.

```
var elem = $(".parent2").find(".child3");
if(elem.length){
    alert(elem.text());
}else{
    alert('Element doesnt exists')
}
```

Alternatively, You can use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
var elem = $(".parent2");
if(elem.has(".child3")){
    alert(elem.find(".child3").text());
}else{
    alert('Element doesnt exists')
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you wrap a selector in `$()` it will always return a jQuery object that contains the array of matching elements.

Therefore you can use the `length` property to test if there are matches

```
var $collection = $(".parent2").find(".child3").length;
if ($collection.length)....
```

You can use other approaches also such as `is()`

```
var #collection = $(".parent2");
if($collection.children().is(".child3") /* returns tru if there are matches
```

Comment: There are lots of approaches, it somewhat depends on use case

Answer (score 5):

As the [docs for `find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) explain, `find()` returns a jQuery object. It has a length propery which can be checked for a successful query.

```
if($(".parent1").find(".child3").length > 0) {
    alert("parent1 child3");
}
if($(".parent2").find(".child3").length > 0) {
    alert("parent2 child3");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(Boolean($(".parent1").find(".child3").length));
console.log(Boolean($(".parent2").find(".child3").length));
    
console.log(!!$(".parent1").find(".child3").length);
console.log(!!$(".parent2").find(".child3").length);

console.log($(".parent1").find(".child3").length > 0);
console.log($(".parent2").find(".child3").length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no element .child3 for .parent2,

```
alert($(".parent2").find(".child3").text());
```

Try this:

```
alert($(".parent2").find(".child2").text());
```

Try this if you want only last item

```js
alert($(".parent1").find("[class^=child]:last").text());
alert($(".parent2").find("[class^=child]:last").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child1">Child1</div>
  <div class="child2">Child2</div>
  <div class="child3">Child3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child1">Child1</div>
  <div class="child2">Child2</div>
</div>
```